# find $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int^n_0t^{x-1}(1-t/n)^ndt$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits

I am asked to find with the help of [this theorem/property](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3644832/if-f-n-to-f-uniformly-and-int-infty-0f-n-exists-then-int-infty-0f) the limit: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int^n_0t^{x-1}(1-t/n)^ndt$$

My attempt:

For my $f$ I will use $t^{x-1}$ since I clearly see that $f_n=t^{x-1}(1-t/n)^n \to f$ uniformly. But how does the integral $\int^{\infty}_0t^{x-1}dt$ converge? Am I doing something wrong? Also, how do I pick a function that is greater than $f_n$ and for which I can show converges? I was thinking of picking $t^x$ for the function $g(x)$ but then $t^x$ is not finite. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Note that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-t/n\right)^n=e^{-t}$.  So, in the OP, $f_n(t)=\xi_{[0,n]}(t)t^{x-1}\left(1-t/n\right)^n$ and $f(t)=t^{x-1}e^{-t}$.  Now, the theorem on uniform convergence applies since $f_n(t)$ converges uniformly to $f(t)$.

---

There is an easier way forward.  For $t\in [0,n]$, $\left(1-t/n\right)^n\le e^{-t}$.  Inasmuch as $\int_0^\infty t^{x-1}e^{-t}\,dt$ converges for all $x>0$, the Dominated Convergence Theorem guarantees that

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^n t^{x-1}\left(1-t/n\right)^n\,dt&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^\infty \xi_{[0,n]}(t)t^{x-1}\left(1-t/n\right)^n\,dt\\\\
&=\int_0^\infty \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\xi_{[0,n]}(t)t^{x-1}\left(1-t/n\right)^n\right)\,dt\\\\
&=\int_0^\infty t^{x-1}e^{-t}\,dt\\\\
&=\Gamma(x)
\end{align}$$

And we are done!

Comment: Your answer is good, but I think it does not answer the question. I think she is using improper Riemann integral, so Lebesgue's dominated concergence theorem is not a good tool. Also, she mentioned the theorem she would like to use.

Comment: @Botond I've edited to address the issue of applying the theorem on UC.

Comment: Thank you :) (+1)

Comment: thank you a lot, but what is $\xi_{[0,n]}(t)$?

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  That is the indicator function.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint* : $\displaystyle \int_0^n t^{x-1} (1-t/n)^n dt = \int_0^1 n^{x}z^{x-1}(1-z)^n dz$ Now use Beta-function.